The correct interpretation of "least number of weights required to weigh any integral number up to X pounds"
This is my first post! It's meant to be more of a light-hearted exploration of an exercise problem. I've pretty much come to terms with this problem and figured someone may want to see me bungle through some number theory...
I'm currently working through "Number Theory" by George E. Andrews and had come across the following question:

"What is the least number of weights required to weigh any integral
number of pounds up to 63 pounds if one is allowed to put weights in
only one pan of a balance?".

I'm aware of the solution as well as other posts on this site dealing with this same problem. My question is more about my own interpretation, as I tend to think about problems in a very strange (often incorrect) way. For example, when I read the above problem, I thought "Let's list out some common dumbbell weights (50lb, 30lbs, 25lbs, 15lbs, 10lbs, etc.) and see roughly the minimum number I have to use to reach 63lbs.". Of course, these weight values are somewhat arbitrary (which is how I knew I wasn't understanding what the question was asking...). Nevertheless, my initial scribbling gave me something that resembled the basis representation covered in the chapter:
1(50lb) + 1(10lbs) + 3(1lbs)
So, I concluded it would take 5 weights. Of course, this isn't correct. I'd noted to myself that those 5 weights alone can't account for every value 1-63 (e.g. 4, 5, 6, 14, etc.).
Immediately jumping to a base 2 representation (per the solution) doesn't seem like a natural direction initially. Although, the more I thought about it, I suppose we'd want to check the smallest basis to represent that number and then go from there.
The alternative base representation did have me wondering about a detail in my interpretation of this problem. Below is the base 3 representation:
63 (base 10) = 2(33) + 1(32) + 0(31) + 0(30) = 2100 (base3)
Which is the correct interpretation of the number of weights:

4 weights (the total place values required to get to that final place value)
3 weights (the sum of each place value used)
2 weights (the number of place values used (i.e., not equal to 0))
something else?

Also, is it correct to say that whatever base we use, each place should be wholly accounted for? That is, although we used 0 of the units place in our base 3 example, we should still count that as the max value ("2") since we need those units to reach smaller values. This is to ensure any number up to the final place value can be assigned.

I'd say two $27$s and one nine would count as three weights. I'm not sure what "each place should be wholly accounted for" means. You could have $63$ one-pound weights and weigh any weight up to $63$ pounds (although of course that wouldn't be the smallest number of weights). Please try to clarify your question(s).

You are asked to find a collection of weights that you can select a subset of that adds up to any number from $0$ to $63$ and count the number in the collection.  As Gerry Meyerson notes in a comment, a collection of $63$ one pound weights will do the job, but requires $63$ weights.  As you say, you can use other collections.  We could follow US coinage and have $4$ one pound weights, a five pound weight, two ten pound weights, and two $25$ pound weights.  You should be able to see we can sum to any number up to $63$ (in fact, $79$) with this collection of $9$ weights.  The binary approach with $1,2,4,8,16,32$ succeeds with just $6$ weights.  You are asked to show that this collection works and that no smaller collection works.  A simple way to show that no smaller collection works is that if you have $5$ weights there are only $2^5=32$ sums you can represent.
